# N-Queens Genetic Algorithm in regards to Selection and Mutation

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, n-queens

Currently my program works for 8-queens, but I am trying to make it work for 22-queens. It takes too long when I run the algorithm for 22 queens. I believe the problem may lie in my way of selecting from a population or the mutation.

```
private Chromosome selectChromosome(Chromosome[] population) {

    Random random = new Random();
    double x = random.nextDouble();
    double accFit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
        accFit += population[i].fitness;
        if (accFit > x && i != 0) {
            return population[i - 1];
        }
    }

    return population[0];
}
```

Not sure if this is how you would do the mutation part

```
 private Chromosome crossOver(Chromosome x, Chromosome y) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int point = random.nextInt(x.state.length);
    int[] state = new int[x.state.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < point; i++) {
        state[i] = x.state[i];
    }

    for (int i = point; i < y.state.length; i++) {
        state[i] = y.state[i];
    }

    // Mutation
    double mutateRate = random.nextDouble();
    if (mutateRate <= 0.05) {
        state[random.nextInt(state.length)] = random.nextInt(state.length);
    }

    return new Chromosome(state);
}
```

Comment: To be clear, the only issue is that it is too slow, right? The way you word it, it seems you are unsure about the correctness of the mutation algorithm too.

Comment: Yes, the only issue is that it is slow. It works for solving the problem of smaller sizes. Was just thinking perhaps I messed something up to reduce its speed. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: If the algorithm works, then StackOverflow is not the right place for this question.  The Code Review site would be more appropriate.  You could probably get some speed up by only allocating your `Random` once, instead of every `Chromosome` selection/generation.